# flutter: [firebase_functions/-1007] too many HTTP redirects

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have 2 Flutter projects setup and configured with the same Firebase project, both the same implementations, just different contexts. However, everything is going smoothly on one project, but on the other, it's throwing the `flutter: [firebase_functions/-1007] too many HTTP redirects` error. I've been stuck on this for days,  any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Cloud Function**

```
exports.createOnfidoUser = functions.https.onCall((request, response) => {
  // const onfidoToken = defineSecret("onfido_token");
  const onfidoToken =
    "xxxx";

  const url = "xxxx";
  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      "Authorization": `Token token=${onfidoToken}`,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      "Accept": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "first_name": "Jane",
      "last_name": "Doe",
      "dob": "1990-01-31",
      "address": {
        "building_number": "100",
        "street": "Main Street",
        "town": "London",
        "postcode": "SW4 6EH",
        "country": "GBR",
      },
    }),
  };
  const resp = fetch(url, options)
      .then((data) => data.json())
      .then((res) => res)
      .catch((err) => {});
  return resp;
});
```

**Dart Function (Called on a button press)**

```
Future<dynamic> getIDAuthToken() async {
    try {
      HttpsCallable callable = functions.httpsCallable('createOnfidoUser');
      final response = await callable.call();
      return response.data;
    } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

**Error full message**

```
flutter: [firebase_functions/-1007] too many HTTP redirects
#0      StandardMethodCodec.decodeEnvelope (package:flutter/src/services/message_codecs.dart:653:7)
#1      MethodChannel._invokeMethod (package:flutter/src/services/platform_channel.dart:335:18)
<asynchronous suspension>
#2      MethodChannelHttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions_platform_interface/src/method_channel/method_channel_https_callable.dart:23:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#3      HttpsCallable.call (package:cloud_functions/src/https_callable.dart:49:37)
<asynchronous suspension>
#4      Auth.getIDAuthToken (package:proj/services/authentication/id_verification.dart:168:24)
<asynchronous suspension>
#5      Auth.getWorkflowId (proj/services/authentication/id_verification.dart:203:20)
<asynchronous suspension>
#6      _IdVerificationPageItemState.initState.<anonymous closure> (proj/services/authentication/auth_widgets/id_verification/id_verification_page_item.dart:126:24)
```

Something to mention, I have tried virtually everything, created a separate project, deleted app & reinstalled, flutter clean, reconfigured firebase, etc.

Thank you!

***Update***
Turns out the issue is only happening in iOS and not Android...

Comment: Cloud function is not returning anything.

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you forget to point your app at the local FirebaseFunctions emulator

```
Future<void> main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );

  if (kDebugMode) {
    try {
      FirebaseFirestore.instance.useFirestoreEmulator('localhost', 8080);
      FirebaseAuth.instance.useAuthEmulator('localhost', 9099);
      FirebaseFunctions.instance.useFunctionsEmulator('localhost', 5001);
    } catch (e) {
      // ignore: avoid_print
      print(e);
    }
  }

  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```